# how to give margin of layout in adapter of list in android?

Tags: android

I want to set the margin of the layout in adapter when I call list view. my condition is, when image set in my layout then the text margin is 15dp and when my image visibility gone then text margin will be 180 dp,how is it possible? can i do this work in xml? if yes then reply me.

Comment: can you post code of your adapter and xml..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            view_holder._feedImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams par=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            par.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.feed_text);

            par.setMargins(60,10, 0, 0);

            view_holder._linear.setLayoutParams(par);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams par1=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            par1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.linearLayout1);

            par1.setMargins(10,10, 0, 0);

            view_holder._linear_ll.setLayoutParams(par1);
```

Answer (score 2):

In the xml of your layout, set the property to your ListView:

```
android:layout_margin="15dp"
```

This will set a margin top/bottom etc.

If you want, you can specify using: `android:layout_marginTop` or `android:layout_margin_Right` (for instance)

--Edited--
From XML:

LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.yourLinearLayoutFileId, null);

In your xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns ="..."
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:margin = "15dp"
   .....
>
```

....

Comment: @ juan Aguuilar Guisado , i want to adjust margin in adapter class of java code,not xml. my condtion is when image set in my layout then the text margin is 15dp and when my image visibility gone then text margin will be 180 dp,how is it possible? can i do this work in xml? if yes then reply me.

Comment: I think almost everything is possible, but I'm afraid I'm not understanding you at all.

Can you give an example with images? I don't know if you want to maintenain the margin, adjusting the layout, if you mean marginTop, marginLeft or general margin... I'd be pleased to answer you.

Comment: LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layoutParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);

Button okButton=new Button(this);
okButton.setText("some text");
ll.addView(okButton, layoutParams); this code is not working in my adapter.

Comment: I always prefer working form xml because it's easier and better for write clean code. In addition you can use "dp" measure for paddings, margins etc. which does not depend on pixel density of every device. I advise you to use the inflater from XML.

I'll edit my answer with use case